# Итератор для обхода контейнера, содержащего указатели

Tags: c++, указатели, итераторы, контейнеры

Не совсем понимаю какими должны быть возвращаемые итератором значения при разыменовании, если контейнер содержит указатели. Тобишь какими должны быть возвращаемые значения для операций:

```
operator*()
operator->()
```

Если бы контейнер содержал обычные значения, то в первом случае это была бы ссылка, а во втором - указатель по которому находится элемент. Я же думаю, что в обоих случаях (если храним указатели), нужно возвращать указаль. Прав ли я? И нужно как-то ли менять объявление:

```
class MyIter : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, MyVal *> {
....
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Вы забыли рассказать, что именно должен делать этот итератор. К чему в первом предложении упоминается какое-то "разыменование"? Что такое `MyVal *`?

Comment: *"Если бы контейнер содержал обычные значения, то в первом случае это была бы ссылка, а во втором - указатель"* А почему случай с указателями должен отличаться? Можно возвращать ссылку на указатель в первом случае, а во втором либо указатель на указатель, либо вообще убрать `operator->` (потому что `iter->m` всегда будет ошибкой).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Закрадывается подозрение, что автор пытается реализовать итератор, который автоматически разыменовывает указатели... Но почему-то автор не удосужился нам об этом членораздельно сообщить. И тогда не ясно, почему в `std::iterator` указано `MyVal *`.

Comment: @AnT обходить контейнер - на мой взгляд это очевидное преднозначение итератора. `MyVal *` - это просто часть примера объявления итератора для контейнера, который содержит указатели

Comment: @AnT что касается "итератора который автоматически разыменовывает указатели" - не надо выдумывать того, чего нет. В вопросе нет ничего подобного

Comment: Ну так если это просто обычный итератор, то результаты этих функций должны иметь "обычные" типы. Эти типы у вас уже есть и так - это `reference` и `pointer` унаследованные из `std::iterator`. Воспользуйтесь ими и все.

Comment: @AnT тобишь это, условно, `MyVal *&` и `MyVal **`?

Comment: Видимо да. Кстати, `std::iterator`-то сделали deprecated в C++17. Пора переходить на ручное вписывание в класс кучи `using`-ов.

Comment: Может кто-то объяснит за что два минуса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете просто не задумываясь использовать унаследованные из `std::iterator` типы  `reference` и `pointer`

```
reference operator*() const
pointer operator->() const
```

(Памятуя, однако, что `std::iterator` является deprecated. И что эти имена будут так запросто находиться только если `std::iterator` не является зависимым базовым типом).

Никакой магии в этих типах нет - это просто ссылка на указатель и указатель на указатель. При этом оператор `->` невозможно будет корректно вызывать через синтаксис "оператора в выражении" (как и должно быть). Он будет вызываем только через синтаксис "вызов функции".

Comment: Это понятно, но меня интересует все-таки типы (особенно `reference`). Не вдаваясь в подробности реализации контейнера, я не могу возвращать ссылку на указатель, только сам указатель. Так что если reference это `MyVal *&` (условно) то этот тип не подходит

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Так надо было это сразу в вопросе сказать, ну. `reference` совершенно не обязан быть ссылкой (см. `std::vector<bool>`), так что замените тип `reference` на просто `MyVal *`, а `pointer` оставьте как `MyVal **`. `operator->` я бы убрал вообще (раз вы не можете возвращать ссылку, то и `operator->` видимо не можете осмысленно написать; и раз он все равно не может быть вызван без слова `operator`, то я так понимаю, его удаление не нарушает требования к итераторам).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а что насчет записи pointer тоже как `MyVal *`? Или это может нарушить правильную работы алгоритмов?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Я бы использовал `MyVal **`, это как-то логичнее. На счет алгоритмов: я тут еще почитал требования к итераторам и понял, что ошибся - `reference` обязан быть ссылкой, а итераторы `std::vector<bool>` не [соответствуют требованиям к итераторам](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool#Notes), так что работа алгоритмов с таким итератором в любом случае гарантироваться не будет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat кстати, по поводу нового использования итераторов, если у меня есть итератор, от которого я наследуюсь, нужно ли мне и в насленике прописывать `iterator_traits`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch В смысле, типы `pointer`, `reference` и т.д.? Если они уже есть в родителе и они правильные, то нет, зачем. Вам ведь просто нужно чтобы ваш класс соответствовал [требованиям к итераторам](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) (полностью, или насколько это возможно).